# Is it Necessary to specify "use core data " while creating an app?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am mid-way in creation of my app , i have not specified "use core data" during the creation of the project . I now want to use "CORE DATA" in my app , is that enough if i add it manually ? what would be the major difference ? OR should i start my project again from the beginning ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also add it to your project, when you want just add the framework related to it and delegate method of `coredata`to add in your `AppDelegate` file, it will work fine. Later you can create a new file like `xcdatamodal` type.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it later too. Just create another project, with core data this time, and copy the behaviour from there (xcdatamodel, the code from the AppDelegate).